macOS – Apple Mail – mails marked as junk cannot be unlabeled
I have some mails regularly put in my junk folder by my mail server.
I often need them to be placed back in Inbox.
But, when doing so (either by moving them manually, either by selecting Message > Move to Inbox), sometimes but not systematically – I cannot say why! –, they keep their brown color.
So I suppose they also continue to be marked as junk, while they are in Inbox.
How can I make this label and brown color disappear ?
I didn't manage to find any option to mark them as desired mail.
I tried to rebuild the mailbox with no effect.
Is it a bug of Apple mail ?
Here is an example of a mail marked as junk in my Inbox folder:

I run macOS Sonoma 14.1.2.
